# Make inserted DOM node not affected by CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I'm trying to develop a Firefox addon/Chrome extension. How to insert a new DOM node to arbitrary place of arbitrary page without being affected by its CSS?

Take a look at this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/za5cop0e/1/. If the web page modify the style of all div under certain node in some way (`display: none` as example), and I inserted my div to it without knowing that `display` is modified, my div will not behave as I expect.

One solution I can think of is to override all standard CSS styles with default value, which is unacceptable. Is there more elegant way to do this, for example, `document.createElement('div', false)`, where the second argument indicates to the browser that this node does not inherit any CSS style from ancestors.

Comment: no, you can't exempt a dom node from css. But you could embed it inside an iframe, where it's in its own little independent world.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I'd prefer to not use iframe, because it will have different position coordinates to its parent/siblings.

Comment: You can create a web component, as they have their own isolated styles. Here is a [good tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom/) on the subject. Beware though that this has very limited browser support ([see this for status on support](http://jonrimmer.github.io/are-we-componentized-yet/)), but if you only have to support Chrome it will work fine.

Comment: If you are including a dom element, you can also include css at the same time that will reset the styles in question. Overriding unwanted styles may be the only possible way to pull this off.

Comment: no idea. didn't even know that CSS supported namespaces. There's my "new thing" for the day...

Comment: That `document.createElementNS()` approach does not work, because the browser will not render non-HTML-namepaced element as HTML element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can embed your own css to the DOM element that you are appending.

So for the DOM element you can add css for just that DOM that will override any other as inline CSS preceeds others

http://jsfiddle.net/za5cop0e/4/

```
var s = document.createElement('style')
s.textContent = 'div { display: none }'; // problematic CSS
document.head.appendChild(s);

// expect to show a black block, but will not show due to the CSS style above
var d = document.createElement('div');
d.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
d.style.width = '100px';
d.style.height = '100px';
d.style.display = 'block'; // here
document.body.appendChild(d);
```

Comment: yes, but the element will inherit ever OTHER style that would apply to it. You'd have to override EVERYTHING, e.g. apply a full css-reset to the element, just to make it "normal" again.